# Video Tutorials for Ab Initio ETL Data Ware housing Tool !

Tags: data-warehouse, etl, ab-initio

Please tell me where I can find video tutorials of Ab-Initio ETL Data Ware Housing tool.

I surfed in google but i did not find any materials.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you will be able to fine these anywhere other then contacting Ab Initio directly.  They do not readily share their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Abinitio have a full non-disclosure policy with their customers. You wont find much freely available on the internet. If you want training in Abinitio (and you are a customer of theirs) then I suggest you contact them directly.